# $httpBackend: Angular Unit-Testing that a GET request is sent

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, httpbackend

I'd like to test that a (component's) controller is sending a GET request to some URL (without caring about the response). I was expecting that

```
httpBackend.expectGET('/some/random/url');
```

would spy on the http backend and fail if it did not get the GET request, so I was expecting the following spec to fail:

```
describe('myApp', function() {
  var httpBackend;

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($httpBackend) {
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
  }));

  it('sends a GET request to /some/random/url', function() {
    httpBackend.expectGET('/some/random/url');
    httpBackend.expect('GET', '/some/random/url');
  });

});
```

But this seems to pass trivially

```
Starting the Teaspoon server...
Teaspoon running default suite at http://127.0.0.1:56255/teaspoon/default
..

Finished in 0.01200 seconds
2 examples, 0 failures
```

with this:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);
```

So I suppose I am misunderstanding what `expectGET` is doing and this is not the way the way to check what I am trying to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually add the following code to any spec (test) files deal with http mocking. This makes sure that the call is flushed and that there are no outstanding expectations / requests.

```
afterEach(() => {
    try {
        $httpBackend.flush();
    } catch (e) {
    } 
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});
```

This would change your code like so

```
describe('myApp', function() {
  var httpBackend;

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($httpBackend) {
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
  }));

  afterEach(() => {
      try {
          httpBackend.flush();
      } catch (e) { // entering here is a sign your unit test failed
      } 
      httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
      httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

  it('sends a GET request to /some/random/url', function() {
    httpBackend.expectGET('/some/random/url');
    httpBackend.expect('GET', '/some/random/url');
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks. `httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();` gives the error I was waiting for. (So you have to flush after each spec explicitly otherwise requested will stick between specs?)

Comment: @sunless - With the `afterEach` it should flush after completion of each `it`. I guess it also depends on how you have your tests structured, with many calls or nested `it` specs you might have to change it up. I prefer one call / test per `it` block so the afterEach works for me in that way.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call `flush()` on httpBackend. That's when it will check that all the expected requests have been received.