# Testing async functions which use await Karma+Jasmine JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, async-await, karma-jasmine

Im trying to test a async function using Karma and Jasmine in an angularjs v1.5.0 project. This async function (a) has 2 await like so:

```
async function a(){
    let var1 = await b()
    console.log(var1)
    let var2 = await c()
}

function b(){
    return $http.get(url1).then(
        function(response){
            ...
        }
    )
}

function c(){
    return $http.get(url2).then(
        function(response){
            ...
        }
    )
}
```

My test:

```
it('testA', inject(async function($httpBackend) {
    $httpBackend.when('GET','url1').respond(200, [myresult])
    $httpBackend.when('GET','url2').respond(200, [myresult])
    MyController().a()
    $httpBackend.flush();
}));
```

The problem is that `$httpBackend.flush();` is only 'flushing' the first await and then the execution of the function 'a' does not continue, it can't even reach the `console.log(var1)`. Can anybody help me with this?

I can't change the code, i just want to make a test for that code.

I tried to do `await a()` in the test, but that just doesnt work, it doesn't event resolve the first await.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the below code, got it from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36433763/httpbackend-angular-unit-testing-that-a-get-request-is-sent)

```
it('testA', inject(async function($httpBackend) {
    $httpBackend.when('GET','url1').respond(200, [myresult])
    $httpBackend.when('GET','url2').respond(200, [myresult])
    MyController().a()
    try {
        httpBackend.flush();
    } catch (e) { } 
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwer, but there is no pending request to flush so verifyNoOutstandingRequest just dont throw any error. Same for the expectations. Thats the problem and i dont understand why. The code only flush the petition of the first await and then stop.